# Is there a way to return a certain value before it goes out of scope for dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Thank you for taking a look at my question. Here is what I have so far.

```
List test() {
// ignore: deprecated_member_use
List<String> newList = [];

FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('userInput/xCj26wS73dslrIXsggrY/userInput2')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((event) {

  event.docs.forEach((docs) {
  
    newList.add(docs['Weight'].toString());
    print('1\n');
    print(newList);//first prints out '0' then '40'
  });
  print('2\n');
  print(newList); //prints out '0 40' this is what i want the value to be
  /**
   * 
   * Is there a way to return here?
   * If i try to 'return newList', i get an error of 'The return type 'List<String>' isn't a 'void', 
   * as required by the closure's context.'
   
   */
 
});
print('3\n');
print(newList);//prints out empty list
return newList;//returns empty list
```

}

I have tried adding comments to make this a little easier to read/understand. I'm trying to access a certain data in a collection and add that value to a list. The issue I am having is by the time i can use a return statement, the variable loses the value I want it to have. Is there a way to call return under where I have ' print('2\n');'? If not, how can i return my list before it goes out of scope? While looking at other recourses, I came across this, which would print out each of the specific data in the collection; however, I want to add each of the data into a new list.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userInput/xCj26wS73dslrIXsggrY/userInput2')
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: streamSnapshot.data?.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Text(streamSnapshot.data?.docs[index]
           ['Exercise']),
           
      );
    },
  ),
 
);
```

}

I would appreciate any tips, feedback, etc.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`return` within your `listen` *callback* makes no sense; where would the returned value go?

Your `test` function returns an empty `List` because it returns immediately without waiting to receive all of the asynchronous events from the stream.  Streams are asynchronous; your `test` function must be asynchronous too.  One way to wait:

```dart
Future<List<String>> test() async {
  var newList = <String>[];

  await for (var event in FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userInput/xCj26wS73dslrIXsggrY/userInput2')
      .snapshots()) {
    for (var docs in event.docs) {
      newList.add(docs['Weight'].toString());
    }
  }
  return newList;
}
```

Or, using collection-`for`:

```dart
Future<List<String>> test() async {
  return [
    await for (var event in FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userInput/xCj26wS73dslrIXsggrY/userInput2')
        .snapshots())
      for (var docs in event.docs) docs['Weight'].toString(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware of 'future' or 'aysnc'. I will study those. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.